# Unexpected ouput generated when using the AdWords keywords generator api

Tags: python, google-api, google-ads-api

When using the Google Adwords API keyword generator given in [this example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201705/optimization/get_keyword_ideas.py), I assumed I would get some keywords related to the query I made ("space cruise"). Instead, I get the following:

```
Keyword with 'space cruise f125bcf7' text and average monthly search volume '5779518' was found with Products and Services categories: [17, 35, 10628, 5].
Keyword with 'red herring b610fbe0' text and average monthly search volume '3613244' was found with Products and Services categories: [56, 57, 43, 10628].
Keyword with 'red herring e969d14a' text and average monthly search volume '4490523' was found with Products and Services categories: [16, 33, 10628, 30].
Keyword with 'red herring 33bb9989' text and average monthly search volume '4773027' was found with Products and Services categories: [41, 10628, 13, 22].
Keyword with 'red herring cc518050' text and average monthly search volume '4650205' was found with Products and Services categories: [12, 10628, 13, 7].
Keyword with 'red herring 5864c829' text and average monthly search volume '5092454' was found with Products and Services categories: [11, 28, 10628, 46].
Keyword with 'red herring ef5efb42' text and average monthly search volume '5313565' was found with Products and Services categories: [26, 44, 10628, 14].
Keyword with 'red herring 8dc2cad8' text and average monthly search volume '4603880' was found with Products and Services categories: [40, 52, 10628, 55].
```

How should the numbers at the end of the "keyword" be interpreted - is there some way to map it to a real word? I looked at their docs but was unable to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers you see at the end are IDs of the product and service category taxonomy of Google Adwords. You can find the human-readable descriptions [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/codes-formats#product-and-service-categories).

Also note that Adwords *test accounts* (which you appear to be using) do not return any meaningful data for the TargetingIdeaService. That's why you see all these **"red herring"** keywords—well played, Google.