# Am I able to use the Keyword Planner API (TargetingIdeaService) with an Adwords test account?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I've been trying to get the Keyword Planner API to work using the Google Adwords Test manager account, but it doesn't seem to be working. Has anyone else managed to do this? It doesn't specify in the documentation whether you can or cannot do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work, yes. Be aware, however, that you will not be receiving real data but [rows upon rows of red herrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012693/unexpected-ouput-generated-when-using-the-adwords-keywords-generator-api).