# The meaning of Value of KEYWORD_TEXT Google Ads API

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I have tried Google Ads API and use it's Targeting Idea Service.

I run the [official demo code](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/901f22e0693e80a5faf8fc32c6c1a63f988b6561/examples/adwords/v201806/optimization/get_keyword_ideas.py), and it works well.
The results look like this:

```
Keyword with "space cruise 99f47fa6" text and average monthly search volume "5956924" was found with Products and Services categories: [18, 28, 10628, 39].
Keyword with "space cruise be08a87" text and average monthly search volume "4497071" was found with Products and Services categories: [16, 18, 10628, 21].
Keyword with "space cruise 7ba29dec" text and average monthly search volume "5486625" was found with Products and Services categories: [48, 60, 10628, 63].
```

My problem is I don't know the meaning of hash code after each keyword text, like `99f47fa6`, `be08a87` or `7ba29dec`.

Is there document explaining it?

Comment: Are you using an API test account? If so, you won't get meaningful data. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012693/unexpected-ouput-generated-when-using-the-adwords-keywords-generator-api).

Comment: @dorian Got it. yes I use test account. Thanks!